# Book about a man and two sons travelling in a train which meets a fatal accident

Tags: identification-request

So this is from early childhood and I don't remember a lot.
Here goes a blurred image of the plot.

A man is travelling in a train with his two sons. The train meets an accident with a lot of people dying. The elder son (s0) goes missing and the younger son (s1) is very depressed about the whole situation. Eventually s0 is able to find s1 but he has a very different personality now. Later it is discovered that s0 's spirit has been exchanged with someone else from the train accident earlier.

Keyword - Aloha
Language - English

This was about 10 years ago.
I remember something that sounds like the keyword being used often in the book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## City of the Dead by Tony Abbot.

Here's a quick look at the summary.

> Could the road to the afterlife be a two-way street?
>
> Derek Stone just turned fourteen. He's lived in the heart of New Orleans with his dad and older brother, Ronny, his whole life. He's a little overweight. He can't hear well out of his left ear.
>
> Oh, and he's on the run from the dead.
>
> Derek never imagined that the dead could be anything but dead. But there's no denying it. They're back -- and they're after him.
>
> He just doesn't know why.
>
> And he doesn't have long to figure it out.
> <sub>*- [City Of the Dead by Tony Abbot - Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/4495481-city-of-the-dead)*</sub>

This seems to match your description pretty well.

Comment: you're a genius

Comment: why thank you @tambakoo :)

Comment: I was going to ask if there was  some more information about the plot, because on the basis of what is posted here, it doesn't bear that much similarity tot he book described in the question, but I see that the book is part of a series and the blurb for the [second book](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/4495482-bayou-dogs) seems to be more specifically a match...'Derek's brother Ronny isn't himself. No, really. Ronny's body has been taken over by the long-dead soul of a man named Virgil Black. Lucky for him, Virgil is one of the good guys. Not all of them are.'